# Close floating action button Android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I used the following library https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button and everything works fine.
How do I close the menu automatically after clicking on one of the buttons on the same menu?

Comment: You can use a easy way to implement FAB_Menu without using any liberary check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40647621/4961126

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its open-source lib, You can read the [source code](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/getbase/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionsMenu.java) and find that by your self.

```
FloatingActionsMenu.collapse(); // close the menu
FloatingActionsMenu.toggle(); // toggle the menu
FloatingActionsMenu.expand(); // open the mneu
```

In the `Click listener` of the `Menu Item` call `.collapse()`

Answer (score 0):

```
FloatingActionMenu fAM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.fAM_ID);

FloatingActionButton fAB1 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fAB_ID);


   floatingActionButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             //Action
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FAB Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


             fAM.collapse();
        }
    });
```