# Android - Custom floating action button?

Tags: android, android-button

How can I have a floating action button can transform into a list of contacts.

(Without any use library for example I don't need to use [THIS](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)).

Like bellow :

[image]

Comment: This is a FloatingActionMenu , which is **not** provided by Android, you'll need to use 3rd party libraries or you can make it **yourself**.
Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699302/android-design-support-library-fab-menu

Comment: You can do this without using any library, or huge code for animation, check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40647621/4961126